# Extracting PCA by variable themes instead of extracting PCA for the whole dataset

Tags: r, pca

I am using a large dataset with more than 4,000 numeric variables and 300,000 observations. I am thinking to use PCA to reduce the dimensionality of it, but I cannot read my dataset into R, because I do not have enough memory for that. These variables are separated by themes, for example Households, People, Reference Person, etc. Would it be theoretically wrong if I extract the PCA by themes for the numeric variables and use it into machine learning models to make predicitions instead of extracting the PCA for the whole dataset?

Comment: Are you unable to read into R using the `data.table` package and its `fread` function?  At any rate, your idea is sound.   Were R to be able to scale to this size problem (it might not) I would have recommended sparse PCA to do what you described.  You can also consider variable clustering followed by regular PCA of each cluster.

Comment: Yes, even with 'fread' function it is too much for R to support in my case.